# Draw route from my location to destination and Lat Lng destination this is coordinates from SQLite

Tags: android

Draw route from my location to destination and Lat Lng destination this is coordinates from SQLite
This code Map.java

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    SQLiteDatabase SQL;
    GoogleMap map;
    myDBClass DB;
    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoint;
    double latitude = 0;
    double longtitude = 0;
    GMapV2Direction md;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_map);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, this);

        // Destination Marker from Database SQLite
        if (MarkerPoint.size() > 1) {
            String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
            DB = new myDBClass(this);
            SQL = DB.getWritableDatabase();

            cursor = SQL.rawQuery("SELECT *" + " FROM " + myDBClass.TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE " + myDBClass.NAME + " ='" + Name + "'", null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            /**String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.NAME));
            double lat_db = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.LAT));
            double lng_db = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.LNG));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat_db, lng_db))
                    .title(name)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));**/
            latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.LAT));
            longtitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDBClass.LNG));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
            drawMarker(point);
        }

        if (MarkerPoint.size() >= 2) {
            LatLng Start = MarkerPoint.get(0);
            LatLng End = MarkerPoint.get(1);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Start).title("Start"));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(End).title("End"));

            Document doc = md.getDocument(Start, End,GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
            int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
            String distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
            String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
            String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);

            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
            }

            map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        }

    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
        MarkerPoint.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /**
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and for the end
         * location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if (MarkerPoint.size() == 1) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        } else if (MarkerPoint.size() == 2) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }

        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        map.addMarker(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (MarkerPoint.size() < 2) {

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longtitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);

            // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
            // map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

            drawMarker(point);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

this code Manifest.xml
I'm this code no problem because is code bacis.

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.test.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>


<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="API_Key"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

I'm edit this code in several days already. Help me plz.

Answer (score 0):

You should orginize more your code, separate the main functions. Not having everything in the activity class. This code is not perfect but maybe that can help you rethink yours, take notes.

THE HELPER CLASS EXAMPLE :

```
public class DrawRouteHelper {
    /**
     * PRIVATE ATTRIBUTEQ
     */
    public final static String  MODE_DRIVING    = "driving";    // TODO: google map Driving or Walking choice
    public final static String  MODE_WALKING    = "walking";

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {

        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {

        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }
                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }
        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            }
            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;
            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

HOW TO USE IT WITH AN INNER CLASS EXAMPLE :

```
    DrawRouteHelper             _drawRouteHelper    = new DrawRouteHelper();
    Document                    _document;
    GoogleMap                   _googleMap;

private class DrawRouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog  Dialog;
        String                  response    = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityGoogleMap.this);
            Dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Get All Route values
            _document = _drawRouteHelper.getDocument(_locationFrom, _locationTo, DrawRouteHelper.MODE_DRIVING);
            response = "Success";
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = _drawRouteHelper.getDirection(_document);
                    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.RED);
                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                        rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                    }
                    // Adding route on the map
                    _googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO:ERROR TRACE ROUTE
            }
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will send coordinates

    if (MarkerPoint.size() >= 2) {
            LatLng Start = MarkerPoint.get(0);
            LatLng End = MarkerPoint.get(1);

go private class DrawRouteTask

answer plz